# cuda driver mismatch, can not use tensorflow gpu mode although gpu is installed

Tags: python, tensorflow

I installed cuda 10.2 to ubuntu 18.04 according to the official documentation, where I used the debian package for the installation

running

```
cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version
```

I got

```
NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  435.21  Sun Aug 25 08:17:57 CDT 2019
GCC version:  gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)
```

nvcc -V

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Oct_23_19:24:38_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.2, V10.2.89
```

when I run tensorflow 1.13.1 or 1.14.1,

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.Session(config = tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement = True))
```

I got

```
    tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:300] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_SYSTEM_DRIVER_MISMATCH: system has unsupported display driver / cuda driver combination


2020-02-17 23:27:09.218431: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2020-02-17 23:27:09.219872: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:318] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_SYSTEM_DRIVER_MISMATCH: system has unsupported display driver / cuda driver combination
2020-02-17 23:27:09.219940: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:169] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: devbox_ailab
2020-02-17 23:27:09.219953: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:176] hostname: devbox_ailab
2020-02-17 23:27:09.220013: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:200] libcuda reported version is: 440.33.1
2020-02-17 23:27:09.220051: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:204] kernel reported version is: 435.21.0
2020-02-17 23:27:09.220062: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:313] kernel version 435.21.0 does not match DSO version 440.33.1 -- cannot find working devices in this configuration
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 13236727771426211181
, name: "/device:XLA_CPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_CPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 8110659726839847577
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device"
]
```

Comment: See here: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#linux  For TensorFlow 1.13.1 or 1.14.1 you need to use CUDA 10.0. CUDA 10.2 is too new to use with TensorFlow.

Comment: To reiterate-- this is a tensorflow question, not a CUDA question. Please tag it as such

Answer (score 2):

As described in [tensorflow's documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu) versions below `1.15` should be installed with specification of `gpu` explicitly, e.g.:

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.14.1
```

Furthermore your cuda version is `10.2` which **is not supported by Tensorflow** (either `tf2.x` or `tf1.x` AFAIK). `1.13.1` and `1.14.1` was compiled against cuda `10.0`.

Your only solution is to compile `tensorflow` with version of your choice against your `cuda` version (see some info [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source)) or rollback to `10.0` (some options described [here](https://dmitry.ai/t/topic/33)).